# pine script: ta.rsi(close, 14) returning NaN

Tags: pine-script

Have this code, returning NaN for the RSI. Been trying to troubleshoot. Any pointers, please?
*var vtrsi = nz(ta.rsi(close, 14), 1)
var idrec = label.new(last_bar_index, close, + ':' + str.tostring(vtrsi), color = color.blue, style = label.style_label_up)*

I have tried number formatting the RSI and to no avail either.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `var` modifier? When variable declared as `var`, it is stores its value between bars.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_var

```
var vtrsi = nz(ta.rsi(close, 14), 1)
```

this way you declared `vtrsi` variable with the initial value of NaN (because at the first bar `rsi` returns NaN), and this value is not changing over the bars, until you will not reassign it value to another one like this `vtrsi := nz(ta.rsi(close, 14), 1)`

This is probably what you want:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

vtrsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    idrec = label.new(last_bar_index, close,  str.tostring(vtrsi), color = color.blue, style = label.style_label_up)
```